# Can someone please help me with this thermodynamics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

[image]

How do you find out if all the steam condenses or not? In the solution, you're supposed to find the energy required to make the steam change temperature to 100 degrees celcius (mc*deltaT) and the energy required for the steam to go through a phase change to become water (mLv). Then you find the amount of heat needed to heat both the water and aluminum to 100 degrees celcius and compare which process requires more heat (steam to fully condense or water + aluminum to reach 100 degrees celcius) to know if all the steam condenses or not. My question is: why do you have to compare the amount of heat needed to condense steam to the heat needed to raise the aluminum and water to 100 degrees celcius as opposed to some other arbitrary temperature? Why is it compared to 100 degrees celcius? Shouldn't you find the final temperature of the system and use that temperature instead of 100 degrees celcius?

Comment: Is the aluminum container supposed to be of constant volume.  If so, there will always be some vapor remaining in the container.  If not, then what?

Comment: I totally agree with your insightful criticism of this problem. Very perceptive!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finding the final temperature **without answering the first question** is a complex and lengthy process.

The usual algebraic method involves setting the final condition to some variable, say $x$, and then setting the heat loss by the hot end equal to the heat gain by the cool end using that variable and solving for the variable.

This method works well for simple systems, like adding some hot metal to some cool water.

However, things get very messy when more components are present, or when phase changes are possible.

In the example cited, there are four possible end states:

1. The steam cools slightly to a final temperature $T$, while the aluminum warms to $T$, and the liquid water warms to $100^\circ$$C$, all the liquid water vaporizes, and the resulting steam warms to $T$; $T>$$100^\circ$$C$
2. All the steam cools to $100^\circ$$C$, while the aluminum and water warm to $100^\circ$$C$, and a fraction $x$ of this warmed water vaporizes;$0<x<1$
3. All the steam cools to $100^\circ$$C$ and a fraction $x$ of this cooled steam condenses, while all the aluminum and liquid water warms to $100^\circ$$C$; $0<x<1$
4. All the steam cools to $100^\circ$$C$ and then condenses and cools to a final temperature $T$, while the aluminum and water warm to $T$; $T<$$100^\circ$$C$

Each of these distinct solutions is possible depending on the amount of steam and its temperature compared to the amount of water.

You would need to set up an equation reflecting each of these scenarios, solve the linear equation and see if the value for the unknown is within the range required.

Only one scenario would give a valid result, but there is no way to predetermine which one.

Throw in some sub-zero ice cubes and the situation gets really interesting.

A preferred method is to assume an arbitrary final state, and find the **imaginary** external heat flows necessary to reach that state.  It is convenient to pick the phase change temperature as the final temperature with all of the water going to the same phase. (In this case, the solution provided seems to arbitrarily pick "all steam at $T=$$100^\circ$$C$ as the final state.)

This will result in some outflow of heat energy to cool the hot phase and an inflow of heat to warm the cool phase.

It is remotely possible that the two heat flows will be equal.  Congratulations!  You have your answer!

More likely, the heat flows will be different.  In order to return to the reality of purely internal heat flow, you need to make up the difference by adding or removing heat.

But now you are applying this corrective heat flow to a simplified system:  some aluminum and some water steam, both at $T=$$100^\circ$$C$.

If you need to add heat to achieve zero external heat flow, then the aluminum and steam warm up.

If you need to remove heat, then some steam condenses.  If all the steam condenses and you still need to remove heat, then the now-liquid water and the aluminum cool off.

All four possible scenarios are covered with no wasted effort.